# Mysql query – Word begins with within the content

Tags: mysql, regex

I'm attempting to replicate the following regex pattern in a MySql query: http://regexr.com/3gt57

I'm unable to use a like as I need to match words that begin with the submitted term but don't necessarily contain the term.

I can't seem to use the pattern in a REGEXP query:

```
SELECT * FROM serialised_post 
WHERE post_content REGEXP '\bSugg\S*';
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL regexp, `\S` = `[^[:space:]]` (a negated bracket expression matching any char other than a whitespace char (`[:space:]` is a POSIX character class matching any whitespace)) and `\b` (here, a leading word boundary) is `[[:<:]]`.

Use

```
WHERE post_content REGEXP '[[:<:]]Sugg[^[:space:]]*';
```

See more details about [MySQL regex syntax here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp).

Comment: This is as I assumed, some differences in the mysql regex engine. I'll give this a whirl! Thanks for your time :)

Comment: MariaDB handles backslash thingies.